# Groovy Static Scope

Tags: groovy

I'm attempting to run this script. If I pull it all out of the class, it runs fine. When I wrap it in my "Test" class, I get this error:

> Apparent variable 'json_users' was found in a static scope but doesn't
>   refer to a local variable, static field or class

```
class Test{

    def testProc(JsonBuilder json_List) {

        println json_List.prettyPrint

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        def query = 'Select * from mytable'    

        def resultset = sql.rows(query)

        json_users = new JsonBuilder(users:resultset)    

        testProc(json_users)
    }
}
```

Any idea why I'm receiving this error?

Comment: Where did you declare the `json_users` variable?

Comment: Is this not declaring it properly? json_users = new JsonBuilder(users:resultset)

Comment: That's assignment, not declaration.  Did you want something like `def json_users = new ...`?

Comment: Yes, this fixes the problem. Though, I'm left with the question as to why it works when pulled out of the "Test" class.

Comment: @John See here for an answer to why it works outside the class: [Groovy program structure - Chapter 3.4. Variables](http://groovy-lang.org/structure.html#_variables)

Comment: Actually, now my testProc is throwing a runtime error. Do I need to declare the parameter as a different type?  --  no signature of method is applicable for argument types  (groovy.json.JsonBuilder)

Comment: `testProc` isn't static...  You need to make it static, or create an instance of `Test`

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple things wrong.  One is that you cannot invoke an instance method from a static method.  Another is that you can't refer to `json_users` without declaring it (you can in a script, but not in a class).

Instead of this:

```
class Test {

    def testProc(JsonBuilder json_List) {

        println json_List.prettyPrint

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        def query = 'Select * from mytable'    

        def resultset = sql.rows(query)

        json_users = new JsonBuilder(users:resultset)    

        testProc(json_users)
    }
}
```

Try this:

```
class Test {

    static testProc(JsonBuilder json_List) {

        println json_List.prettyPrint

    }

    static void main(args){

        def query = 'Select * from mytable' 

        // you will have to declare and initialize
        // the sql variable.

        def resultset = sql.rows(query)

        def json_users = new JsonBuilder(users:resultset)    

        testProc(json_users)
    }
}
```